# Getting spaces with Boost::regex

Tags: regex, boost, spaces

I have a chunk of text like:

*Name=Long John Silver;Profession=cook;Hobby=Piracy*

And using the Boost::regex library I am trying to get the value of each attribute so I have the following regular expression for Name:

```
regex(".*Name=([^;$]*).*")
```

I understand it as "get everything after *Name=* until you find a ; or the end of line". However what I am obtaining using `regex_match` is only "Long", no spaces. Of course I have been trying with several RE combinations but I am not able of working it out.

Any clue?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, inside a character class (the square brackets) the `$` has no special meaning. It simply matches the literal `'$'`.

Try this regex:

```
Name=([^\s;]*)
```

The character class `[^\s;]` matches any character *except* a whitespace character and a semicolon. The name is now captured inside the first match-group.

EDIT:

And if you want to match the entire name "Long John Silver", use this regex:

```
Name=([^;]*)
```

Comment: It is not working that way :(
I want to obtain the complete string including spaces ("Long John Silver"). I have tried with Name=([^\s;]*) and Name=([^;]*) but I only obtain "Long". Thanks.

Comment: See the edit. But you say you tried `Name=([^;]*)` and that this also captured only `"Long"`? I can't imagine that. I don't use this Boost regex engine, but all the regex engine I do use will capture the entire name with the regex `Name=([^;]*)`. Perhaps you forgot to recompile your code?

Comment: You were completely right, I was using the wrong algorithm (regex_match instead of regex_search) and also the wrong data source.
Many thanks!